# Gimp 2.0 export only in JPG regardless what I choose

Tags: gimp

I am trying to save a file as png but no matter what I do when I export it as png it is becoming a jpg file.

[image]

Comment: Gimp 2.0 is really old. The Gimp in the Ubuntu 18.04 repository is v 2.8. Which version of Ubuntu are you using and how did you install Gimp?

Comment: Did you try saving it with a filename ending in `.png`? It looks like "select file type (by extension)" is on.

Comment: @user68186 Must be at least Gimp 2.8, cue the "Export" button :)

Answer (score 1):

The file name in the file at the top `tr2alekos.jpg` ends in `.jpg` so Gimp saves as a JPEG. The Selector on the right is just a filter for the display, what counts for the file type is the selector on the left (the one that currently says `Select File Type (by extension)`). With that selector:

- if set to `Select File Type (by extension)`, then what counts in the extension in the name of the file at the top.
- if you open it and click one of the format descriptions, then Gip will use that format. The extension of the file name at the top is changed accordingly, but you can override that by rewriting the extension, and save a PNG in a .JPG file or vice-versa (you will get a warning but you can override).